# Add custom search keywords in Shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware6

Currently I am using the EAN field for custom search words, when adding more words it becomes unworkable.

This is what I use to update the product using API:

```
    if (isset($productDataArray['ean'])) {
        $productRecord['ean'] = $productDataArray['ean'];
```

It works as it uses only string.

Does anyone know how to change it so it will be updated in the search keywords.
As per shopware documentation it uses `array[object]`.

Hope someone can help.